# Subtracting a constant value from a column without round-up

Tags: perl, shell, awk

I have a file like this.

```
Column1 Column2 
-3500 value1
-3480 value2
-3460 value 3
9920 value 50
9940
9960
10000
10020
40000 Last value
```

Look at this example:

```
awk 'NR>1{$1=$1-4.91}1' file
Column1 Column2
-3504.91 value1
-3484.91 value2
-3464.91 value 3
9915.09 value 50
9935.09
9955.09
9995.09
10015.1
39995.1 Last value
```

I would like to have the correct value, not the rounded like this:

```
Column1 Column2
-3504.91 value1
-3484.91 value2
-3464.91 value 3
9915.09 value 50
9935.09
9955.09
9995.09
10015.09
39995.09 Last value
```

I am trying to subtract a constant value `4.91` from the first column. Everything works fine until `9980`, but starting at `10000`, awk is subtracting only `4.9` from the data and gives values `0.01` lesser than the original ones.I think it is rounding upto some decimal places, but I don't want the rounded values.Can anybody suggest me a workaround..

Anyother suggestions from shell script or Perl are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be done in perl:

```
perl -pe 's/^([-0-9]+)/$1 - 4.91/e' your_file
```

Details:

- `-p` reads file line by line and prints it
- `-e` runs perl code with line content in `$_`
- `s/.../.../e` - replace regexp by expression

  - `^([-0-9]+)` - matched any digit and/or `-` sign. Also captures matched fragment.
  - `$1 - 4.91` - does the work using value captured by regexp.

Comment: Say I wanted to minus 8 instead, from the second column of a file.  Can we still do that in one line of code or would we have to expand a bit?


`perl -pe 's/^([-0-9]+)/$1 - 8/e' your_file > output.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it with `awk`:
You simply set how many decimal you like using the `printf` function.

```
awk 'NR>1{printf "%.2f\n",$1-4.91}' file
-3504.91
-3484.91
-3464.91
9915.09
9935.09
9955.09
9995.09
10015.09
39995.09
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{CONVFMT="%.2f"} NR>1{$1=$1-4.91}1' file
Column1 Column2
-3504.91 value1
-3484.91 value2
-3464.91 value 3
9915.09 value 50
9935.09
9955.09
9995.09
10015.09
39995.09 Last value
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{$1=sprintf("%.2f",$1-4.91)}1' file
Column1 Column2
-3504.91 value1
-3484.91 value2
-3464.91 value 3
9915.09 value 50
9935.09
9955.09
9995.09
10015.09
39995.09 Last value
```